# How to render the images (from users device) which are pasted into a contenteditable div of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

When the image (from the user's device) along with the text is copied from MS Word and pasted inside the content editable div, it does not render the image as the content is copied as HTML. But, if only the image is copied it is converted as base64 string, which works fine.

```
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="mso-no-proof:yes">
<img width="96" height="96" src="file:///C:/Users/dv-Sagar/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.png">
</span>
This is a image
</p>
```

But, after some research, I got to know pasting the image along with the text as HTML is working fine in the TinyMCE editor. But, in my case, it is a Chrome extension so I can't use TinyMCE.

PS: TinyMce somehow converts the pasted image into a URL (using the developer provided server).